# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express 'Group by' across 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to combine in order to do a `group by` function on them.  The reason I'm dealing with this issue is that combined the 2 tables are > than the `10 GB` database limit in `SQL Server Express` (each is ~ 9 GB).  The second table is just a continuation of the first.  It looks like this:

```
  CustId        Sale
    001         4.25
    002        15.24
    003         8.78
    004       122.99
    005        44.80
    ...         ...
```

If it was one table I'd just use something like this:

```
select CustId, sum(Sale) sumSale
from table1
group by CustId
```

Is there a way to combine lengthwise instead of width-wise?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `union`:

```
select CustId, sum(Sale) sumSale
from (
    select CustId, Sale
    from table1
    union all
    select CustId, Sale
    from table2)
group by CustId
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me a union would help here:

```
Select custId, sum(sale)
  from (select custid, sale
          from table1
         union 
        select custid, sale
          from table2)
 group by custId
```